# What is a good way to pause a thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, 2d

I'm creating a java 2D platformer game, and I'm having a little trouble getting an animation to go through when the player dies. When the player dies, all enemies are removed and an explosion animation is played where they used to be. At the same time, the player begins to blink. I want that to go on for about two seconds, and then have my `setState()` method switch to the "PlayerDeadState", which is basically the retry or return to main menu option screen. I've used `Thread.sleep()`, but it doesn't work, and I've heard it's bad for GUI threads. 
Here is my code:

```
public void update() {
// check if player is dead
        if(player.dead == true) {

            player.flinching = true;

        for(int i = 0; i < enemies.size(); i++) {
            Enemy e = enemies.get(i);
            e.update();
            e.hit(200);
            if(e.isDead()) {
                enemies.remove(i);
                i--;
                eExplosions.add(
                    new Explosion(e.getx(), e.gety()));
            }   
        }



        gsm.setState(3);
    }
}
```

The animations go through if I comment out my `setState()` method. The problem with this is the fact that I can't have both currently. Animations, or loading a necessary GameState. I want both. :P

Any suggestions?

Comment: So essentially when the you are in a Thread sleep stage, everything will stop until the sleep is complete. What you need to do is have a state check on everything. if the player is in a dead state, then that means everything else should not be active and not using thread.sleep() (just because it stops the whole thread in general)

Comment: Ah. I figured as much. What I'm trying to accomplish is to have the animation play before I change the GameState. Without some sort of pause, the animations do not play and the GameState changes almost instantaneously after the player dies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use of swing timers:

```
ActionListener listener = new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
        gsm.setState(3);
    }
};
Timer timer = new Timer(2000, listener);
timer.setRepeats(false);
timer.start();
```

Comment: I hadn't thought about swing timers. Thanks a lot! :D